# Foco em Elementos HTML com javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código. Este código contem 5 divs onde ao clicar sobre cada uma ,a que foi clicada recebe um valor de background.Quero que após clicar em uma delas,no próximo clique, a que foi clicada perca o beckground sem alterar as demais.

EX.:Cliquei na div 1 ,ficou vermelha.Cliquei na div 2 ,ficou vermelha,Cliquei na div 1 perdeu a cor vermelha ,mas a 2 tem de continuar vermelha.

```js
 $(function () {
 
 
 $('.Classe').click(function () {
 
 $(this).css('background','red');
 
 
 });
 
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<div class="Classe">valor 1</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 2</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 3</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 4</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 5</div>

<html/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vc pode criar um classe que chama `.ativa` por exemplo e usar o método toggleClass para colocar e retirar o background vermelho quando clicar.

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor. Repare que no primeiro clique eu adiciona a classe `.ativa` que tem o background vermelho, e no segundo clique eu faço o `toggleClass` para remover essa classe assim retirando o vermelho do fundo.

```js
$(".Classe").click(function(event){
   $(this).toggleClass("ativa");
});
```

```css
div.ativa {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="Classe">valor 1</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 2</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 3</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 4</div>
<div class="Classe">valor 5</div>
```